# how to write the mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

table: `taxonomy_index`

```
nid          tid   
2              1
3              1
3              4
3              5
4              6
4              1
4              3
4              7
```

table: `taxonomy_term_data`

```
tid           vid          name
1              2           java
2              2            php
3              2            c
4              1           tag1
5              1            tag2
6              1            tag3
7              1            tag4
8              1            tag5
```

now i want to according to  `nid=$nid` get the `name` where `vid=2`.? how do i do?

the following is my query code. but it's wrong.

```
$result = mysql_query('select tid,name form taxonomy_index as ti left join taxonomy_term_data as ttd on ti.tid=ttd.tid where vid=2 and nid=$nid')
```

Comment: i put the code in phpmyadmin, it shows you have an error in your sql syntax

Comment: the sql looks good, see @GWW answer, i also change "select tid,name" to "select ti.tid,name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you need to replace your single quotes `'` with double quotes `"`.  This is because PHP does not expand variables surrounded by single quotes.

```
$result = mysql_query("select tid,name from taxonomy_index as ti left join taxonomy_term_data as ttd on ti.tid=ttd.tid where vid=2 and nid=$nid")
```

EDIT:

You also have `from` misspelled as `form`

Comment: select tid,name form taxonomy_index as ti left join taxonomy_term_data as ttd on ti.tid=ttd.tid where vid=2 and nid=2 ,i put this in phpmyadmin's sql run box, it shows an sql error #1064. why?

Comment: I just told you why you have `from` misspelled as `form`

Comment: i am sorry. i am too carelessly

Answer (score 1):

I think variables in single string quotes are not substitued, therefore try

```
$result = mysql_query('select tid,name from taxonomy_index as ti left join taxonomy_term_data as ttd on ti.tid=ttd.tid where vid=2 and nid='.$nid)
```

Comment: i put this code in phpmyadmin, it shows an sql syntax error. why?

Comment: select tid,name form taxonomy_index as ti left join taxonomy_term_data as ttd on ti.tid=ttd.tid where vid=2 and nid=2

Comment: @zhuanzhou: check my answer you have from misspelled as form.