# PHP script for search and display datas from database tables connected with foreign key

Tags: php, sql

[image]

These are two tables with foreign key enquiry_id.  Please help me to do a search and display the data of these tables combined like enquiry_id, enrollment_id, installment_date, installment_receipt, installment_amount and student_name, student_contact, student_address, Student_course from student_installment_table and student_enquiry_table.

Comment: Search how? For what? You want us to write the search engine for you?

Comment: It sounds like your question is for sql, not php... If you know how to write the SQL your question should be more along the lines of, "How do I query a database in PHP" which you would find answered repeatedly on this site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166225/how-to-write-the-mysql-query

Comment: This is for my website project of an IT Training institution. They need full records of the students who came to inquire and who all are enrolled and the fee details of the enrolled students. So I created a database called students and tables which i given before. I wrote a php script for displaying the details of inquired students in tables by using a HTML search form. Now i want to display the details of enrolled students who paid fees when I do search through HTML.For that I need a HTML search form & php script.

Comment: If I search by enquiry_id in a html form, it should display the matching result from the database in a html page. That is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT enrollment_id, installment_date, installment_receipt, installment_amount, student_name, student_contact, student_address, student_course FROM student_installment_table INNER JOIN student_enquiry_table ON student_installment_table.enquiry_id =  student_enquiry_table.enquiry_id
```